# How to create Image slideshow with slide left/right animation using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on simple solution which requires image slider.
Right now it is just fading in and out. i would like to add some slide animation

I can simply do it using `jquery` but i don't want to use any external libraries.

```js
var counter = 0;
var slideImgs = [
  "http://placesforkidsct.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/300x250.png",
  "https://abbs.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/self-development-300x140.jpg",
  "https://abbs.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/self-development-300x140.jpg"
]
var imgelm = document.getElementById("300x250_Image");
var inst = setInterval(change, 1500);


function change() {
  //  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  imgelm.src = slideImgs[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= slideImgs.length) {
    counter = 0;
    // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
  }
}
change();
```

```html
<div class="300x250_section_3" style="float: left;margin-top: 13px;">
  <div class="300x250_center_img" style="
        width: 300px;
     height:140px;
        float: left;
    ">
    <img src="http://placesforkidsct.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/300x250.png" style="width: 300px;text-align: center;display: block; margin:auto; max-height:140px;
    " id="300x250_Image" class="slide_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this you want to like Image slider?

Comment: Yes ! but without using jquery!

Comment: I think this link useful for you https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/pIfoD